# Listbox with 1000+ items freezing Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, listbox

I have a listbox with 1091 items in it, which I am adding during design time.  Every time Visual Studio tries to save after I manually populate the listbox it will hang indefinitely.  Is there any way around this, am I trying to add too many items to a listbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing it manually city-by-city at design time, I would simply loop through a text filee (or excel file or database) at runtime and add all of the cities to a list, which then is used to populate the listbox.

Of course, this isn't the answer to your current question, but this may be a solution to your current problem.

**Update**: Resource Files might be a happy medium. You can still keep your city names in some sort of a text file.  Then, you add that text file to a resource file. The resource file is then integrated with your program so you don't have to deal with a user ever knowing that the file exists.

I tried it out in C# (my preferred language) and it was more simple than I expected. After adding the resource file Resource1, I added my textfile cityListTextFile.txt to Resource1. From then, I could access it like this:

```
string cityList = Resource1._cityListTextFile;
```

After that line of code, I had all of the contents of cityListTextFile.

Take a look at this tutorial on using resource files in [VB.NET](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/netres090117.htm) and a [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) one for fun.

Comment: I considered doing this but I have to have the same list of cities in the listbox every time, it will never change.  I would prefer to not have to distribute a text file with a list of cities in it just to populate a listbox upon execution of the program.

Is there a way to read the text file once and save it to the listbox permanently and no longer require the text file?

Comment: @RHOMBUS Updated with a solution that wouldn't involve any external files after compiling.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this should work well.  I'll give it a try.  Good to find out something new as well.

Comment: @RHOMBUS Actually, this was something new to me.  Although I've used resource files for language localization, I hadn't used them for anything else. However, I remembered I could add more than just strings to the resource files. So, I explored that and it turned out resource files could be quite useful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Why put so many values on a listbox on design time? Try to add on execution time, so your VisualStudio doesn't hangs.

Comment: It is a list of cities so each item in the list box is unique and cannot be programmatically inserted with a loop and incremental variable.

Comment: @Rhombus : 
That does not make sens, you should do it in code, not in design time; even simply as manually add each item in the list.
pseudo code : 
list.AddItem("Montreal");
list.AddItem("Paris");
list.AddItem("San Diego");

Comment: I realize I can add it in the code but I do not wish to go through 1091 items and add ListBox.AddItem("City1") . . . ListBox.AddItem("City1091")

Comment: I am copy&pasting the items, not typing each in individually.  That's not exactly tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the listbox from repainting while you update it:

```
 listBox1.BeginUpdate()
 Dim num As Integer
 For num = 1 To 3000
     listBox1.Items.Add("Item " & num.ToString())
 Next num
 ' End the update process and force a repaint of the ListBox.
 listBox1.EndUpdate()
```

Comment: I am setting the list of items during design time.  Anytime Visual Studio tries to save (closing a form, run-time, etc.) it will freeze.